# Jquery copy form inputs with keyup

Tags: jquery, forms

**Solved** Needed to use the val instead of text. My mistake!

What is the difference when copying a form field to another form field vs copying a form field to a span id?

I can copy from input field to a span id no problem, but using the same method to copy from form field to another form field doesnt work.

Using Jquery keyup

Can anyone enlighten me?

Heres a **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LnDYA/19/)**

Thanks in advance

```
    <input type="text" name="Quantity" value="100"  id="quantity2" />
    <input type="text" name="Quantity" id="quantity_img2" />

    $("#quantity2").keyup(function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $("#quantity_img2").text(value);
    }).keyup();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the value of textbox element use `val()` method instead of `text()`.

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/LnDYA/20/

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#quantity_img2").text(value);
```

should be

```
$("#quantity_img2").val(value);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/LnDYA/21/)**

#### Why this happen

Because `#quantity_img2` is an `input field` , a `form` element and to set value to `input` field require [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) method.

So your code should look like

```
$("#quantity2").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("#quantity_img2").val(value); // not .text()
}).keyup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val) in place of `.text()` like this

```
$("#quantity2").keyup(function () {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("#quantity_img2").val(value);
    }).keyup();
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/LnDYA/23/)

Answer (score 0):

I created a Jquery plugin called val2 that detects span vs input and just sorts out when to use $().text() vs. $().val(). After using val() on a span and wondering why it was broken only to slap forehead and say, "of course, dummy... its a span!" I created this plugin:

```
$.fn.val2 = function (newVal) {

    // Jquery Plugin to improve upon $().val() and agnostically handle get/set of values for a span or input (type="text")
    // http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/
    // use, get mode: var val = $("#" + id).val2(); 
    // use, set mode: $("#" + id).val2("fred"); 

    if (this !== undefined) {
        // newVal indicates set vs get mode
        if (newVal === undefined) {
            var ret = "";
            if (this.attr("value") === undefined && this.prop("value") === undefined)
                ret = this.text(); // this is a span
            else
                ret = this.val(); // this would be an input
            return ret;
        }
    else {
        if (this.attr("value") === undefined && this.prop("value") === undefined)
            this.text(newVal); // this is a span
        else
            this.val(newVal); // this would be an input
        }
    }
};
```

Usage Examples:

Get mode:

```
var txt = $("#MySpan").val2();
var txt = $("#MyInput").val2();
```

Set mode:

```
$("#MySpan").val2("fred");
$("#MyInput").val2("fred");
```